# Java code to download a file or a zip file

Tags: java

I am using below code to download a file and it works fine for small files, but when I tried to download a file whose size > 11GB code is not working and giving `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` exception

```
public String downloadDirectory()
{

     OutputStream myOut = null;
     FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
     File downzip = new File(dirName+"/"+dir+".zip");


   getServletResponse().setContentType("TEXT/HTML");
   getServletResponse().setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"" + dir +".zip" + "\"");
   getServletResponse().setContentLength((int)downzip.length());
    System.out.println("length  "+(int)downzip.length());
     //READ DATA FROM FILE

            byte[] dataRead = new byte[(int)downzip.length()];
               fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(downzip);
               fileInputStream.read(dataRead,0,(int)downzip.length());
    //WRITE DATA TO OUTFILE
               myOut = getServletResponse().getOutputStream();


          myOut.write(dataRead);

           if (fileInputStream != null) {                       
               fileInputStream.close();
           }



    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
         Execute.rmdirscript(dirName);
        return "exception";
    }
     finally{
        System.out.println("finally downloaddir");
    if(myOut!=null){
        try{
        myOut.close();}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
    }
    if (fileInputStream != null) {                       
               try{
        fileInputStream.close();}
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();;
        }
           }
}


}
```

The error is at this line:

```
byte[] dataRead = new byte[(int)downzip.length()];
```

The value `(int)downzip.length()` becomes negative for big files and gives `java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException` exception.

Comment: which line does the error come?

Comment: 11GB is too big to fit in an `int`. And what's your question?

Comment: I also hope you have a way of resuming the download. Getting 90% of the way through 11GB and having to start again will be rather painful.

Comment: u mean this line 
new byte[(int)downzip.length()] ??

Comment: The max value to fit in an int is about 2 GB. If your file is 11 GB, it will overflow and might result in negative values.

Comment: what modifications shall i do in my code to enable big files download?

Answer (score 3):

didn't you try in a loop? like this

```
 byte data[] = new byte[1024];
 int count;
  while ((count = in.read(data, 0, 1024)) != -1)
            {
                    out.write(data, 0, count);
            }
```

Comment: sure, get back in case you face any issues

Answer (score 2):

You are reading data size in long and down casting it into int, which is not safe, and is causing the negative array length. Actually your file length should be 0 if I go by this code, and the length may not be negative but simply zero.

As a solution, try writing directly to a file instead of creating an array upfront. Also, allocating 11G memory for array is anyway not a good idea.

You can create a `FileOutputStream` from the output file path and then read from the `InputStream` and write to `OutputStream` until you reach the end of stream `-1` that should safely copy file for you.

Comment: what modifications shall i do in my code to enable big files download?

Comment: @ankit you are downloading the whole file at once, you should never do that, even for small files. Use an internal buffer and iterate with a loop to download the file in smaller chunks

Answer (score 1):

You are storing it into byte array for which 11 GB is quite big to store that,  i think there is the problem occur.

Please provide the exact line where you got the error.

Comment: The error is at this line:

byte[] dataRead = new byte[(int)downzip.length()];

the value (int)downzip.length() becomes negative for big files and gives java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException exception.

Comment: you are trying to convert downzip.length() into int, you can store it using for loop, in one iteration you store only the size of byte (not int) and than write it into the file and continue the loop until all data are copy.

Answer (score 0):

Java use int for array indexing. The `Intger.MAX_VALUE` is `2^31-1`. You can store only `2^31-1`bytes `2GiB` in a regular array.

Comment: what modifications shall i do in my code to enable big files download?

Comment: You should use 64bit java implementation, if you want to work the whole bytes, and split your array to smaller pieces. If you just save them, just read it to a buffer and write them.

Answer (score 0):

It is the length of `File downzip` that causing you a problem.

`downzip.length()` returns `long`, which you explicitly cast to `int`. That way you easily get negative value with which you initialize array:

```
byte[] dataRead = new byte[(int)downzip.length()];
```

Another thing is you should avoid reading a whole file. Better way would be reading and writing it in chunks.

You have example of how to do this in @Ashok Raj's answer.

Comment: yes u r right what modifications shall i do in my code to enable big files download?

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
private static void readFileAndDumpIt(String pathToFile, OutputStream out){
    try {
        InputStream fIs = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(pathToFile));
        byte[] array=new byte[4096];
        for(int numberRead=fIs.read(array);numberRead!=-1;numberRead=fIs.read(array)){
            out.write(array,0,numberRead);
            out.flush();
        }
        fIs.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have successfully used it, on up to 20GB files